# Unknown directive in NGINX default.conf

Tags: nginx

I accidently deleted my default.conf file.  Luckily, I copied and pasted the original text into another file.  My problem is, when I try to start NGINX after creating a new default.conf file and pasting in the text using nano editor, I get the following error:

unknown directive " " in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:3

I suspect the pasted text is injecting some unneeded stuff.  If I'm correct, how do I identify that and clear it out?

Here's what I'm  adding to the default.conf file:

```
server {
        #listen       80;
        server_name  xr7tsi.com www.xr7tsi.com;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/client/server_logs/host.access.log main;
    location / {
            root   /home/ubuntu/client/build;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
        }

    large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    server_tokens off;
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xr7tsi.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xr7tsi.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.xr7tsi.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = xr7tsi.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  xr7tsi.com www.xr7tsi.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Comment: The unknown directive looks like a "space" characters. Could the file contain a character that looks like a space, but is not U+0020?

Comment: Thanks, Richard.  I think you're probably right.  Now I have to figure out how to get those spaces out.  Preferably without re-typing the whole thing.